# Import one module from other in YII

Tags: php, yii

I have two different modules in YII- event, invitation.

While I work with invitation module I would like to access the other module.
How do I import this?

Comment: do you want to use models from another module?

Comment: Yes I want to use models from another module

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use event models in invitation, then add below code in your invitation module InvitationModule.php init()

```
public function init()
{
  // importing al models, components from event
  $this->setImport(array(
            // already you have list for invitation module

            'event.models.*', // event is alias name for event module.
            'event.components.*',


        ));

}
```